# Should I create a "bug resolved" tag?

Tags: discussion

I've been participating on this question:

[Javascript Remoting Update causing INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD for Integers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54778/javascript-remoting-update-causing-invalid-type-on-field-in-record-for-integers)

It is definitely a bug. It's been accepted by the VF team as a bug. If I can track its progress, once resolved, it might be nice to flag it as such. I would probably add an update to the post...or ask the original author to do so. But having a flag of resolved bugs that Salesforce has fixed, might be useful.

Thoughts.

Comment: May help to elaborate on what uses you consider this useful for ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wouldn't.

I believe tags are to classify questions, not to express the state of an answer or solution. The tag bug doesn't indicate whether it's about a fixed bug or not (even-though you could state that a fixed bug is no longer a bug). In that context such tag may confuse users.

Personally I would just update the question with:

"**update  yyyy-mm-dd:** this bug has been fixed by salesforce, see reference X"

Comment: I would say it isn't really about the state of the answer or solution, but the cause of the question in the first place. Still, I see the point.

Comment: I think this approach is best. Acknowledge that the bug existed at one time, and give some basic info about its resolution. Too often I search and find outdated questions or bugs on the internet, with no idea of any updates. In a world of sparse and stale information, this would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not useful. It would be [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). If the bug is solved, an answer saying that it was solved can be posted and accepted. Because in the time when the bug isn't solved it there would be answers-workarounds. Finally, answer saying that bug is solved posted and it is also an answer, but it doesn't invalidate other answers.  At last, Stack Exchange forums are not specifically designed to report bugs (except per-site metas, where site-related bugs can be reported, and [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com)).